# Link in running text on mobile device

Tags: mobile, hyperlinks, text

we have a mobile app with a space of 1 row for running text on the first screen. It´s purpose is to announce an important news. For example: "We are preparing a new version of our app with lots of new features."

The problem: This running text is a link as well. It leads to the extra page with "article-like" text. What is the best practice to show this running text as the link? How to inspire users to click on it?

Right now they add something like "for more info click here", but the same text is technically the title of the article, so we have an article with a title like "We are preparing a new version of our app with lots of new features. For more info click here". It´s awkward.

Don´t ask me why they prepared it technically to be the same text. To change it is more complicated than do something with the visual of the running text.

I aprreciate any advise or a good practise axample. Thanks.

Comment: Clarify a couple of things, are you saying the title is the link to the article and nothing else?

Comment: Well.....We have a mobil app. On the first screen (login screen) right at the top is a space of 1 row. There is running across the screen this text: "We are preparing a new version of our app with lots of new features. For more info click here" This whole text is a link to the separate screen consisting of a title a text. In the text is further info ahout the new version, but the problem is, that the title is the same text as the running text. Like this we have a title containing "For more info click here". That is the problem.

Comment: Can you simply add static button like "Read more..." in the same unit with running text? Or with a small 'click' icon on the button?

Comment: When you say 'running,' please tell me it's not a marquee?

Answer (score 1):

Have you monitored it and the clickthrough rate is not good ? Because news tickers on websites were known that it lead users to focus on those and interact with them.

"News tickers" are a thing of a past. Used broadly along many website from FT, CNN in the past they have been ditched. Why ? Because a user will not know how long that is , the user is not in control etc.

I personally would drop the ticker and make a dismissible box containing the text.

Other than that the person who coded the site can have the Read more text not be a part of the article title anyways.

Comment: I´m not a fan "running anything" either. Of course my first reaction was "change the logic of the same texts in the running text and in the title" but they are unable to change it now. Instead I have got a quest to find out how to make the running text look "clickable" without the "click here" add. The "click here" was aded after complaints from Helpdesk that user doesn´t know what is the running text and how to interact with it. I can´t find any good solution, there I ask here.

Comment: Clickable text is underlined and colored differently commonly so maybe you can start there. 

The title itself in this case is not "asking" for a click. You could maybe try something like "What`s new in our future release" or something that prompts for action.